# How to compare two matrices on MatLab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Given a matrix A and a matrix B, how do I compare them element by element so the program returns a third matrix C that shows:
- If the element in A is larger than the one in B, the element in C should be 1.
- If the element in A is smaller than in B, the element in C should be -1.
- If the elements of both matrices are equal, the element in C should be 0.

Hope you can help!

Comment: Hi, you should post some code - what have you tried, why problems you are having etc.

Comment: Try C  = sign(A - B)

Answer (score 2):

```
C=zeros(size(A));
C(A>B) = 1;
C(A<B) = -1;
```

Note that it's never a good idea to do an equality test on floating point numbers.